# SwiftUI Chaning Animations

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I am trying to chain two animations in SwiftUI. However, the first animation does not animate when pressing the button. I found this approach of chaining animations here: [Chaining animations in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907344/chaining-animations-in-swiftui)

```swift
struct FancyButtonViewModel: View {
    @State var movementY:CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("")
                .offset(y: movementY)
            Button("Press Me"){
                withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    movementY = -150
                }
                withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 3).delay(0.5)) {
                    movementY = 0
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The emoji should first move within 0.5 seconds 150 pixels north and after that within 3 seconds back to its origin. The first animation is not smooth, it directly jumps to 150 pixels (no animation there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by using DispatchQueue and async after a while. So remove the delay from the animation and pass it to the DispatchQueue.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var movementY: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("")
                .offset(y: movementY)
            Button("Press Me"){
                withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    movementY = -150
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 3)) {
                        movementY = 0
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```